# Ajax and sting concatenation causing problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, playframework

Working with Play! 2 framework which I have to say has been brilliant to work with so far, just coming across a few snags with AJAXy stuff.Some code example will help to explain.

This is in the View...

```
@(travelgroup: TravelGroup, user: User)

var theUrl = "http://localhost:9000/groupdata/" + @travelgroup.id.toString() + "/" + @user.email.toString() + "";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: theUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        wypoints.push({
           location:val.toString(),
           stopover:true
        });
    });
    }
});
```

This is the route...

```
GET     /groupdata/:id/:user            controllers.TravelGroupController.getGroupData(id: Long, user: String)
```

This is the console error I'm getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Highlighting the below as the culprit...

```
var theUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/groupdata/' + 1 + '/' + jeff@example.com + '';
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doign wrong? ANd please ask if you need any further details

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected token is the `@` - you're missing quotation marks around that email address. You want it to be rendered as:

```
var theUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/groupdata/' + 1 + '/' + 'jeff@example.com';
```

So try:

```
var theUrl = "http://localhost:9000/groupdata/" + @travelgroup.id.toString() +
             "/" + "@user.email.toString()";
```

Note that the `+ ""` that you had on the end is redundant so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks dude... thats worked great! I'd give you a plus 1 too but my rep not nigh enough yet :-/